# Problem 7.2 9 of Velleman's How to prove it (Big O of a countable set of functions)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, maxima-minima

I'm having some trouble with this problem:

> Suppose $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \{f| f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is countable. Prove that there is a function $g: \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq O(g)$.

The hint for the solutions is

> First note that if $\mathcal{F}=\emptyset$ then $g$ can be any function. If $\mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$, then since $\mathcal{F}$ is countable, we can write its elements in a list: $\mathcal{F} = \{f_1, f_2, \ldots\}$. Now define $g:\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ by the formula $g(n) = \max \{|f_1(n)|,|f_2(n)|,\ldots,|f_n(n)|\}$.

Now I can see how this $g$ would work if $\mathcal{F}$ is finite, but what about if it is denumerable (countable and infinite)?

If $\mathcal{F}$ was defined as $\{f_k|k\in \mathbb{Z^+}, f(n)=k\cdot n\}$, then I can not see how $\max \{|f_1(n)|,|f_2(n)|,\ldots,|f_n(n)|\}$ can exist for any $n$. For $n=1$ this is the set of all integers, which is not even bounded from above and therefore can not have a maximum.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your definition of $\cal F$ makes no sense.

Comment: How do i write it then? I want it to include $f(n) = n$, $f(n) = 2n$, $f(n) = 3n$,...

Comment: Do you want the family $\{f_k\mid k\in\Bbb N, f_k(n)=k\cdot n\}$? In that case, $g(n)=n^2$ will dominate $\cal F$.

Comment: Yes, this is the function I wanted. Although I still don't see how this would for for an infinite set (see my comment to your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that any finitely many integers have a maximum. You begin by enumerating your $\cal F$, and it doesn't really matter how, and at the $n$th step you just ensure that your value is greater than the first $n$ functions *in the enumeration*.

Your definition of $\cal F$ makes little sense, but it is also not a problem, because you *first* need to enumerate your $\cal F$, and then you can define $g$.

---

<sub>Of course, $g$ may depend on the enumeration, but it dominated over $\cal F$, that's the important point.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If i understand correctly, your answer uses something like induction? The way I understand it is that this will prove that there is such a function $g$ for a finite set with cardinality $n$. But would this also prove that there is such a function for a denumerable set?

Comment: No, the point is that here at each step you take the maximum of a *larger, but still finite,* set of values.

Comment: And how does this prove that a maximum exists for an infinite set of values?

Comment: It doesn't. But you're not defining a maximum over an infinite set of values. Look at the definition of $f\in O(g)$ again. Where does it say that $f(n)\leq g(n)$ *for all* $n$? (Hint: nowhere! :-))

Comment: Alright, now I get it. Thanks!